# Return html form field on AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have requirement to create dynamic field with dynamic labels when user gives input, to be more explicit :

**I ask the user to select a date range and according to that date range i want to create label and input field for each dates**

---

For that what i did was to call `AJAX` function on change event of input form field and according to the input i process in `php` function and `echo` the template to the page and attach it to the form like below

```
$('#setdates').click(function() {

startDate = document.getElementById('event-start_date').value;
endDate = document.getElementById('event-end_date').value;

$.ajax({
    url: "showtimings",
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
        'startdate': startDate,
        'enddate': endDate,
    },
    success: function(result){
    $("#optionTemplate").html(result);
  }});

});
```

And following is just the template of what i am returning from function depending on input. This template multiplies for the number of time entered by user

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <label>Date is Dynamic</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
        <select class="form-control" id="starttime0">
            <option>00:00</option>
            <option>01:00</option>
            <option>02:00</option>
            <option>03:00</option>
            <option>04:00</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
        <select class="form-control" id="starttime0">
            <option>00:00</option>
            <option>01:00</option>
            <option>02:00</option>
            <option>03:00</option>
            <option>04:00</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then according to the that i echo the `html` template from `php` function and attach it to the page.

I wants to know that is this a good practice or is there any other way i can make it more efficient?

Even right now its takes a good amount of time to return the data and attach it to the form so i think its because of the call to the function. Is there any other way to make it process quickly?

Comment: Is there something in particular you need to get back from the server that couldn't just occur client side?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy actually  no there isnt. But i found it very difficult to create field using javascript so i thought of this.

Comment: What does the HTML look like? What properties of this element need to be  dynamic?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I have added the code of html and in that the labe of date is dynamic. Form gets the days between 2 dates and create label and input field for each days with the date as label.

Comment: You don't need the ajax no ? I mean, you can do everything with JS ? (It's not really clear what you want to do)

Comment: @Blag i am asking user to select date range. and according to that date range i want to create label and input field for each dates.

Comment: @MikeRoss ok, so no need to php/ajax, Jquery'll be far enough ! could you edit your post to make two sample of what you get back with you ajax ? (I need to understand what are the changing part) and add your base date form (make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LS2Ek/270/) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit]

Here is a version that gen by himself (in vanilla JS) a set of fields. I don't exactly know your need, so you'll have to adjust it to get what you want

```js
    function genTemplate(startDate, endDate) {
        var buffer = '';

        startDate = new Date(startDate).getTime();
        endDate = new Date(endDate).getTime();
        day = new Date(startDate);
        var timediff = endDate - startDate;
        nbDay = Math.floor(timediff / (1000*60*60*24));

        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < nbDay; i++) {
           day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1);
           buffer = buffer +
            '<div class="row">'+
                '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">'+
                    '<label>'+day.toDateString()+'</label>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">'+
                    '<select class="form-control" id="starttime0">'+
                        '<option>00:00</option>'+
                        '<option>01:00</option>'+
                        '<option>02:00</option>'+
                        '<option>03:00</option>'+
                        '<option>04:00</option>'+
                    '</select>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">'+
                    '<select class="form-control" id="starttime0">'+
                        '<option>00:00</option>'+
                        '<option>01:00</option>'+
                        '<option>02:00</option>'+
                        '<option>03:00</option>'+
                        '<option>04:00</option>'+
                    '</select>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>';
        }
        return buffer;
    }
    
    function f() {
        startDate = document.getElementById('event-start_date').value;
        endDate = document.getElementById('event-end_date').value;
    
        optionTemplate = document.getElementById("optionTemplate");
        optionTemplate.innerHTML = genTemplate(startDate, endDate);
    }
```

```html
start <input id="event-start_date" value="2015-11-10"><br>
end <input id="event-end_date" value="2015-11-15"><br>
<button onclick="f()">Run</button><br>
<hr>
<div id="optionTemplate">
</div>
```

Comment: thats exactly what i am doing right now. And my template is in the question. In there only part needs to be changes is the date `label`. Doing this was my first instinct but i was thinking of doing something else because i dont feel its a good practice to include html part directly in jquery

Comment: @MikeRoss here is the snippet, change for your need